# Form validation in vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am trying to understand and work around to validate a simple form but the problem I am facing is, when the page loads, it shows the "Error" or "Success" message, which should display only either on `keypress` or `mouseout` event.

Moreover, I cannot figure out how to validate the dropdown and finally when a user click submit, it can check all fields are filled and correct to submit the form. Following is my code and my link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mahassan/qrsf524u/65/)

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" @keypress="checkField" v-model="name">
    <span v-if="checkName">Checks out </span>
    <span v-if="!checkName">Pleas enter valid name</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="Age">Age</label>
    <input type="number" @keypress="checkField2" v-model="age">
    <span v-if="checkAge">Enter Valid Age </span>
    <span v-if="!checkAge">Not a valid age</span>
  </div>

<div>
  <select name="" id="">
    <option disabled selected>Please Choose</option>
    <option v-for="gender in genders" :value="gender">
      {{gender}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <span v-if="genderField">Please select a gender</span>
  <span v-if="!genderField">Green means go</span>
</div>
 <div>
   <button @click="checkSubmit(e)">Submit</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 data: {
    name: "",
    checkName: "",
    age: "",
    checkAge: "",
    genders : ["Male",'Female',"Other"],
    genderField: "" 
  },
  methods: {
    checkField() {
      if (!this.amount) {
        this.checkName = true
      }
    },
    checkGender() {
                if(!this.genders){
            this.genderField = true
        }
    },
    checkSubmit(e){
        //check if all fields are filled before submitting
      alert("it is working")
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  }

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to validate forms. I have a few tips for this kind of case.

1. Use a `form` element with `@submit.prevent="..."` event handler. It will ensure a better user experience;
2. Do not use `@key*` event handlers to validate or format a value, instead, use `@input`. It will prevent you from a lot of headache;
3. [Vue provide a API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) to watch all the attribute changes, not only when the user changes it.

For solve your problem, you can create a `validation` attribute and set its content acording the other attributes change.

See the example below:

BTW: I recommend that you take a look on [vuelidate](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/)

```js
const app = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      name: null,
      age: null,
      gender: null,
      genders: ['Male', 'Female', "Other"],
      validations: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit(e) {
      const keys = Object.keys(this.validations);

      // required fields
      const required = ['name', 'age', 'gender'];
      for (const key in required) {
        if (!keys.includes(required[key])) {
          alert('Please, insert a ' + required[key]);
          return;
        }
      }

      for (const key in this.validations) {
        if (!this.validations[key]) {
          alert('Please, insert valid ' + key);
          return;
        }
      }
      alert("ok");
    }
  },
  watch: {
    name(newValue) {
      this.validations.name = newValue > '';
    },
    age(newValue) {
      this.validations.age = newValue > 0;
    },
    gender(newValue) {
      this.validations.gender = this.genders.includes(newValue);
    }
  }
});

app.$mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="submit">
    <div>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" v-model="name">
      <span v-if="'name' in validations && validations.name">Checks out </span>
      <span v-if="'name' in validations && !validations.name">Pleas enter valid name</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="age">Age</label>
      <input type="number" v-model="age">
      <span v-if="'age' in validations && !validations.age">Enter Valid Age</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="gender">Gender</label>
      <select name="gender" v-model="gender">
    <option disabled selected>Please Choose</option>
    <option v-for="gender in genders" :value="gender">
      {{gender}}
    </option>
  </select>
      <span v-if="'gender' in validations && validations.gender">Green means go</span>
      <span v-if="'gender' in validations && !validations.gender">Please select a gender</span>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Vuelidation is nice.thank you, how does validations get populated? it is not connected to any model. I never used watch, where is watch methods get executed? and when you do `age' in validations && !validations.age` what does first part do? and when u say use `@submit` what is the difference between using it or `@click` I am not a pro in JS (sorry)

Comment: `validations` is populed in `watch` methods. `watch` methods are executed when the attributes changes ([reference](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)), in this case, when user inputs some value. `'age' in validations` checks if the watcher was executed and `validation.age` has some value. I think `@submit` is better than `@click` because user can submit a form pressing the `enter` key too, not just clicking on the button. If your question was answered, please, flag it.

Comment: Still confused about how `'age' in validations` works.

Comment: `'age' in validations` is a flag that means: "has the validation been done?". The initial value of `validations` is an empty object, so `'age' in validations` returns `false`. When `age` attribute changes the watcher is executed validating its value and setting `validations.age`. After that, `'age' in validations` returns `true` regardless `validations.age` being true or false.

Comment: In another words: `'age' in validations`means: "Has the user input some value on `age` field?"

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, we have a built-in option to validate forms. But Vue offers very limited functionality when it comes to create and validate forms. To add more functionality, we have to install a separate package called Vuelidate to validate our Vue application forms.

**What is Vuelidate?**
According to the Vuelidate [website](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/):
“Vuelidate 2 is a simple, but powerful, lightweight model-based validation for Vue.js 3 and Vue 2.x.”

**Install**

```
npm install @vuelidate/core @vuelidate/validators
```

**Reference:**
https://aaqibqs.medium.com/learn-form-validation-in-vue-3-in-10-minutes-with-vuelidate-8929c5059e66